# Processmaker 4: setting up packages

Tags: processmaker

Sorry for being a noob at this.

I have installed ProcessMaker4 from the Bitnami image and am working towards having some packages and connectors.

From what I understand packages are separate instances (much like a microservice) that connect to ProcessMakerthrough connections (the bit you install in ProcessMaker).

Does anyone have a guide on how to install a connector and how to set up a package? There are apparently a lot of packages available to install, but I have found no guides or anything to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear that they are part of the enterprise version of the software.
https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker-release-notes/processmaker-4.1-release-notes/non-core-package-versions